# Django JSONWebTokenAuthentication not working for views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using

> rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication

for my REST APIs . This is working fine for authentication but for my Skill view , I am able to hit the REST endpoint even though I am not passing any authentication token .

How can i make my Skill API authenticated . Also I am new to Django so In the User view I do have a class , but for my Skill view i didnt found a correct example to have a class .

Please help me with this .

I have following view file :

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


@api_view(['GET'])
def skill_collection(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        skills = Skill.objects.all()
        serializer = SkillSerializer(skills, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def skill_element(request, pk):
    try:
        skill = Skill.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Skill.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = SkillSerializer(skill)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Url file :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/login/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url(r'^refresh-token/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^user/$', DetailsView.as_view(), name='rest_user_details'),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/skills/$', wantedly_app_views.skill_collection),
    url(r'^api/v1/skills/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', wantedly_app_views.skill_element)

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add JWT authentication by adding following permission in settings.py

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
```

Please comment if this is right